# How to assign System.Data.Linq.Binary to null in C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, hash, linq-to-sql

I have an SQL Server table with a column `NameHash` with type `binary(16)` which allows nulls.

In my C# application, I have a very basic MD5 hashing extension method:

```
public static byte[] CalculateMD5HashBinary(this string input)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
    {
        return null;
    }

    MD5 md5 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create();
    byte[] inputBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input);

    return md5.ComputeHash(inputBytes);
}
```

I am using `LINQ to SQL` to assign the value:

```
var fooBar = MyContext.FooBars.First();
fooBar.NameHash = fooBar.Name.CalculateMD5HashBinary();
MyContext.SubmitChanges();
```

When `Name` is null or empty, the `NameHash` column should be null. However, when I save this value in the DB, I check the values I see the hex string `0x00000000000000000000000000000000` instead.

Why does it do this? How can I get a null value properly assigned into the `NameHash` binary column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out after some messing around.

`LINQ-to-SQL` takes the `Binary(16)` SQL-Server type and makes it of type `System.Data.Linq.Binary` in C#.

You can assign `Byte[]` values to `Binary` variables and do boolean comparisons the two, so I was using them some-what interchangeably.

What I realized is that my extension method of return type `Byte[]` was setting `{""}` to the `NameHash` value instead of null for whatever reason. I changed the return type to `Binary` and it solved my problem.

```
using System.Data.Linq;

public static Binary CalculateMD5HashBinary(this string input)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
    {
        return null;
    }

    MD5 md5 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create();
    byte[] inputBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input);

    return md5.ComputeHash(inputBytes);
}
```